# How delete duplicate Wordpress posts in DB

Tags: sql, wordpress, mariadb

When I run this code on my wp_posts table (using phpmyadmin), it returns a single duplicate post.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_type, a.post_status
FROM wp_posts AS a
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
   FROM wp_posts
   WHERE post_type = 'post'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   GROUP BY post_title
   HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
 ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

Note that this given post is actually not a duplicate, it only has the same title as another one (a normal behaviour given the code above looks for duplicate titles). However, the problem is that there are actually hundreds of duplicate posts in the database (I can see them if I look manually), so why can't I find them using the above code?

- I can also see those two duplicate posts from the wordpress admin panel...
- I also tried to use a few Wordpress plugins and they all found the same duplicate post as the code above, but none of the others).

Edit : If I look at two random duplicates, one has:

```
ID 9462
post date 2017-03-07 13:06:31
post content "foo"
post title "Les pendules à l'heure"
post status "publish"
post type "post"
guid "http://www.exemple.com/?p=9462"
```

The other has:

```
ID 11409
post date 2017-03-07 13:06:31
post content "foo"
post title "Les pendules à l&#039;heure"
post status "publish"
post type "post"
guid "http://www.exemple.com/?p=9462"
```

Thanks

Comment: when you manually look at the database, are you checking the post_type and post_status match your query ?

Comment: I added some more info in my post. Yes, post_type and post_status match. @lan Kenney

Comment: @Lan Kenney, Sorry... I just edited my post again... It looks like they do match when displayed in the browser, but when looking at the code I see one has "  '  " while the other has &#039; . Maybe I need to fix the special characters first? Which one should I be keeping in my database? The "  '  " or the &#039; ?

Comment: I tried: UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE (post_title, '&#039;', '\''); but I don't think I can use an html special char inside my sql query?

Comment: Why won't the above UPDATE code work? If I use: SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%'%", it returns 1825 results, and when I use SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%&#039;%", I get 720 results...

Comment: Ok, I got it to work... The UPDATE command was in fact working. I was simulating the query and it returned an error, but when I ran the query (no simulation), it worked. So I successfully, removed all the  &#039; from the DB and now when I run my original code, it selects 560 posts that are duplicates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I managed to fix my problem...

I noticed that even though the titles looked the same between the duplicate posts, one had an apostrophe while the other had &#039 ;

So first I ran this query to see how many post titles had apostrophes:

```
SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%'%",
```

It returned 1825 results. Then I ran the following command to see how many post titles had &#039 ;

```
SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%&#039;%"
```

It returned 720 results. So I figured I would replace all the &#039 ; by apostrophes, using the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE (post_title, '&#039;', '\'');
```

Then, I was able to use:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_type, a.post_status
FROM wp_posts AS a
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
   FROM wp_posts
   WHERE post_type = 'post'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   GROUP BY post_title
   HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
 ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

Which returned 572 posts, which I simply deleted using:

```
DELETE a.*
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'post'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 0):

The above way can be slow. You can do it the BIG BOY way...

-- Create temporary table CREATE TABLE posts_temp_table LIKE wp_posts;

-- Add constraint ALTER TABLE posts_temp_table ADD UNIQUE(YOUR_UNIQUE_FIELD, id);

-- Copy data INSERT IGNORE INTO posts_temp_table SELECT * FROM wp_posts;

-- Rename and drop RENAME TABLE wp_posts TO old_wp_posts, posts_temp_table TO wp_posts; DROP TABLE old_wp_posts;

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this

DELETE a.*
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'post'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: That is not what I want to do. I am only looking to SELECT the duplicates for now. I will be deleting them when using SELECT returns the duplicates.